# can you make material ui tab responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tabs, material-ui

Is it possible to make the material ui tab react component **responsive**?

[Documentation of MATERIAL UI TAB](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/)

Say I have multiple tab items with a search bar like below

[image: Edit Material demo]

I want to make the input component stretch the whole width of the screen for mobile view (screen less than 500px)

I tried putting width: 100% on the tab with media queries but it didnt work.
I also wanted to remove the focus effect when i click on the search component which is illustrated below

[image]

To summarise

1 ) **I want the input component to stretch the whole width on smaller screens**
2 ) **I want to remove the focus effect when clicking the first tab(search component)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example, forked from your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fpfw5?file=/demo.js.

Basically I changed something for only screen sizes smaller than 600px:

- First, set "max-width" and "width" for first tab to "100%".
- Second, set width for input inside `tab1` to "100%.
- Last, add `disableRipple` attribute to first tab.

One thing, I use the default breakpoints of Material-UI, which defined here: https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/

If you wanna change to 500px, just define your own breakpoint.

Comment: one more question, when i try to create a submit button i get a warning in console saying i cannot have a button inside a button (since tab itself is a button i guess) how would i get rid of this message?

Comment: @SeoiMin
You can change the component of that `Tab` into `div` by using `component` attribute in `Tab` like `<Tab component="div" />`.

In that component, you can use another submit button.